# How to convert fs::read to Read trait?

Tags: rust

Here I am reading a file into input variable. Now I need to send this input variable to other function which accepts `Read`.

```
impl Deserial for Module {
    fn deserial<R: Read>(source: &mut R) -> ParseResult<Self> {
        let len: u32 = source.get()?;
        println!("length {}", len);
        let contracts = deserial_map_no_length_no_order_check(source, len as usize)?;
        Ok(Module {
            contracts,
        })
    }
}
```

```
let input = std::fs::read("/home/omkarsunku/Desktop/decodedarraybuffer28122021").unwrap();

let val = Module::deserial(&mut input); this is throwing error as the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<u8>: traits::Read` is not satisfied

the trait `traits::Read` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vec<u8>` does not implement `Read`. But [`&[u8]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-2) does, so does [`Cursor<Vec<u8>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-16).

Try with:

```
let val = Module::deserial(&mut &input[..])
```

Naturally, if you do not need the data in memory, you can pass an opened file to `deserial()`, as `File` [does implement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-3) `Read`.

```
let mut f = std::fs::File::open('filename').unwrap();
let val = Module::deserial(&mut f);
```

And depending on the nature of that `deserial` function it may be much faster to use a [buffered input](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/struct.BufReader.html):

```
let f = std::fs::File::open('filename').unwrap();
let mut f = std::io::BufReader::new(f);
let val = Module::deserial(&mut f);
```

Comment: Thanks @rodrigo for your quick response. Here I tried let val = Module::deserial(&mut &input[..]); it still throwing error as the trait bound `&[u8]: traits::Read` is not satisfied and as you suggested std::fs::open is not working since cannot find function `open` in module `std::fs`

Comment: About the `std::fs::open()`, my fault, it should be `std::fs::File::open()` (and a trailing `.unwrap()`). About the `&[u8]: traits::Read`... on second read, it should say `std::io::Read`, not `traits::Read`. I assumed it was an alias, but maybe it is a different trait with the same name?

Comment: For this lines of code 
let mut f1 = std::fs::File::open("/home/omkarsunku/Desktop/decodedarraybuffer28122021").unwrap();
        let val = Module::deserial(&mut f1); // Here it is throwing error as the trait bound `std::fs::File: traits::Read` is not satisfied

the trait `traits::Read` is not implemented for `std::fs::File`

Comment: For this lines of code 
let f = std::fs::File::open("/home/omkarsunku/Desktop/decodedarraybuffer28122021").unwrap();
        let mut f = std::io::BufReader::new(f);
        let val = Module::deserial(&mut f);
the trait bound `std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>: traits::Read` is not satisfied

the trait `traits::Read` is not implemented for `std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>

Comment: @OmkarSaiSunku Which confirms my theory that this `traits::Read` is unrelated to `std::io::Read`. If that is true, my answer is useless, but then you should add where that `traits::Read` comes from, an external crate, I assume? Can you find out which one?

Comment: Here is Read trait comes from https://github.com/Concordium/concordium-contracts-common/blob/main/src/traits.rs#L40

Comment: @OmkarSaiSunku: Well, that `Read` is [implemented](https://docs.rs/concordium-std/1.0.0/concordium_std/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-2) for `Cursor`, but that is not `std::io::Cursor` but a [type specific for that crate](https://docs.rs/concordium-std/1.0.0/concordium_std/struct.Cursor.html). Try with `deserialize(&mut Cursor::new(input))` or ``deserialize(&mut Cursor::new(&input[..]))`` something like that.